# when zoom level is changed, add or remove pushpins from a map based on OpenStreetMap from C# VS2013 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I  would like to do pushpin clustering on a map based on OpenStreetMap from C# VS2013 WPF.

I am using XAML map control lib (http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/) and a push pin clustering lib (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Pushpin-Clustering-with-29f4b9f4). The lib can do the pushpin clustering and I can add them to the map.

But, I want to add the pushpins to the map when the map's targetzoomlevel is greater than a threshold such as 12.

When I zoom out and the target zoom level is smaller than 12, I need to remove all pushpins and replace them with a heatmap image.

How to make the pushpins added or removed as the zoom level is changed ?

I have tried to add pushpins to a layer.

```xml
<map:MapPanel x:Name="myPushpinLayer" 
              MouseLeftButtonDown="MapMouseLeftButtonDown" MouseRightButtonDown="MapMouseRightButtonDown"
              MouseMove="MapMouseMove" MouseLeave="MapMouseLeave"
              ManipulationInertiaStarting="MapManipulationInertiaStarting"/>
```

```cs
map.ViewportChanged += (s, a) =>
{
    foreach (var entity in myData)
    {
        myPushpinLayer.Children.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

But, no points shown on the map.

Comment: Handle the ViewportChanged event in the Map class and check the ZoomLevel property.

Comment: @Clemens, you mean when viewportchanged event is raised, set a condition to run Cluster() ? Example, set _map.targetzoomlevel > 12 ? But, how to remove the pushpins when I zoom out ?

Comment: Yes, but it may be called quite often (e.g. during animated changes of the ZoomLevel or Center properties), so you probably need a mechanism to delay your processing. You could for example start/stop/restart a timer.

Comment: @Clemens, when I ran "_map.Children.Clear()", all map tiles are cleared too. The map is blank. I want to keep them and only delete the pushpins.

Comment: Put the pushpins into a separate MapPanel (which you add to the map once). Even better, use a MapItemsControl. See the sample application for how to add items from a view model to a MapItemsControl.

Comment: And please stop posting the same question here and on the Discussions page on Codeplex. Post them here *or* there, not both.

Comment: @Clemens, sure, thanks, please see the UPDATE.

Comment: And please do not post comments into the question text. But yes, that was what I meant.

Comment: @Clemens, I used "MapBase mapbase = new MapBase();" " mapbase.ParentMap = map;",  "mapbase.Children.Add(_options.RenderEntity(entity))" , I think "mapbase" is a map layer that will be overlayed on the parent map  ? But, when I added points to mapbase, none of them are shown on the map. I got the same problem for "MapPanel mapPanel = new MapPanel();"

Comment: As said before, use a **MapPanel**, and add that to the top level map control. It's also not necessary to set the ParentMap property, because that is done automatically. Take a look at the sample application to find out how things works.

Comment: Because the code is too long to show in comments, I have to post it in OP. Thanks!

Comment: The MapPanel is a child of a Map? What's the purpose of the Mouse and Manipulation handlers? `entity` objects are Pushpins that have their MapPanel.Location property set? You really want to add all elements from myData to the MapPanel each time the ViewportChanged handler is called???

Comment: @Clemens, entity is the list of points that I need to mark as pushpins on the map. I need to add them to the layer (the MapPanel) and then add the layer to the map. Are there more efficient ways to do this ?

Comment: @Clemens, I need to add them as a layer and also when zoom level is changed, the pushpins can be clustered. I have built a pushpins clustering lib with XAML map control lib. But, I do not know how to add them to a MapPanel.

Comment: I already told you how to do that. Add a MapPanel to the Map. Add Pushpins to the MapPanel's Children collection. Or better, use a MapItemsControl with a view model, as shown in the sample application (with Pushpins!). I'm going to stop this discussion here.